# What's the best way way to download files from a live blog?

Tags: transfer, download

I'm having trouble figuring out a way to download files from a live blog. To be more specific, I'm trying to download the directory and php files that this blog consist of, and work on those files on my local environment while still keeping the original blog live on the net for the time being. I tried to use FTP(filezile) to download the files remotely, but it failed to open the files for writing and the file transfer failed. I then attempted to go into godaddy control panel and change the file permissions but, for some reason, it won't let me do that. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The best way is to use FTP.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need to contact GoDaddy and ask them what to do, FTP *should* work just fine.